# How to add attributes to connected elements

Tags: qgis, line

I have a Points dataframe (shp). Those Points are connected via a lines (polylines, each element only connects two points) (shp). I would like to choose manually two points (in the picture the yellow one). And then I want to add two attributes (lets say connection_ID_1 and year_1) to those lines which connect those two points.
Additionally I want to add those attributes to those points, which are connected via the line (the two yellow one, but also the grey one which I didn't choose, but is in the middle.)

In my hole dataset it is possible that my points have several connections (not more than 5). So the approach should be open to add more column e.g. connection_ID_2 year_2....

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Should this only happen to the selected features, or in one operation for the whole layer?